# Python - How to make pm2 working with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, node.js, pm2

So I found new issue regarding pm2 (pm2.keymetrics.io/) - So I have been trying to figure out why my scripts didn't work with pm2

(What I mean by pm2 is that whenever you run with multiprocessing it creates a python.exe and open it up separated from PM2 Dashbord like picture here 
[image: Picture])

So the question is how can I possible make it working for Pm2 dashboard.

I made a quick little script for those who want to test it out with pm2.

```
import multiprocessing, time, os, sys, threading
from utils import Logger

Checker = ['Helloworld']
logger = Logger()  # Logger from Utils

def test(findings):
    while True:

        logger.log("ping")
        time.sleep(1)


def main():

    try:
        jobs = []
        for finding in Checker:
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=test, args=(finding ,))
            jobs.append(p)
            p.start()


    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Keyboard - Interrupted')
        sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Keyboard - Interrupted')
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: could you please add what commands you exactly run in your shell

Comment: @BraveButter I just write `pm2 start test.py` - I did realized if I remove multiprocessing.Process - it does write in the Global Logs but as soon as it is in the code it opens python.exe file instead and runs through there

Comment: @Hellosiroverthere Have you solved this? I am also trying to get a python service running with PM2 which makes use of the multiprocessing lib. Without any additional config it starts up in "cluster" mode in PM2, but there is no PID assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to successfully run a python program that uses pythons `multiprocessing` lib is to force running it in fork mode. PM2, if not told otherwise, automatically tries to run it in cluster mode.

However, I suspect, we need to leave the multiprocessing part to python completely. I can't imagine PM2 being able to manage the multiple processes being spawned by the multiprocessing of python.

I am starting my process from a `pipenv`, so here is my corresponding **pm2.config.json** file:

```
{
    "apps": [{
        "name": "BackupService",
        "script": "/home/service-backup/service/server.py",
        "args": [""],
        "exec_mode": "fork",
        "wait_ready": true,
        "autorestart": false,
        "max_restarts": 5,
        "interpreter" : "pipenv",
        "interpreter_args": "run python3"
    }]
}
```

The important part here is `"exec_mode": "fork"`

Then `pm2 start pm2.config.json`. I always `pm2 delete BackupService` (or whatever you call it in "name"), before starting again, because even with the `--update-env` flag it does not make use of a updated pm2.config.json. Don't know why.

If you **dont** use a pm2.config.json file then (I think) you can force fork mode by passing the `-i 0` flag to pm2 start. If anyonce could test and confirm this, I'd like to update this to make a certain statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is my setup for PM2, and Python multiprocessing:

```
// ecosystem.config.js generated using `pm2 ecosystem`

module.exports = {
  apps : [
    {
      "name": "<Your_Service_Name>",
      "cwd": "C:<Your_Working_Directory>",
      "script": "./app.py",
      "exec_mode": "fork_mode",
      "wait_ready": true,
      "exec_interpreter" : "C:<Your_Path_To_venv>/Scripts/python.exe",
    }
  ],
};
```

After running `pm2 start <Your_Path_To_Ecosystem>`, it will spawn a window that contains your other process. In this case, I specifically have Tensorflow models in my directory (also reason for the "cwd" configuration for relative path) which I needed to use in the other process.